# Regex, wordpress, and Search Regex plugin - removing affiliate links

Tags: regex, wordpress, replace

I have a wordpress blog(s), in which I am trying to use plugin named '**Search Regex**' to remove a part of post text, that I've placed as advertisement on the bottom (don't ask)

Now, I'm spinning around for a few months trying to find a proper answer on this, I know mysql doesn't support regex fully, and it would probably be painful to even try doing it that way, so I decided to use this plugin.

My wordpress blog have couple of thousands of posts, with almost the same code on the bottom, and code looks something like this:

```
    <!--more-->
    <br />
    <center>
    <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#000000" style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
    <a href="http://myaffiliate.com/?q2=affiliateid" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" ><img title="blabla" src="http://someimage.com/somewhere></a><br />
    <a href="http://myaffiliate.com/?q2=affiliateid" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><b>Some random Blah</b></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </center>
```

Everything outside   is fixed and doesn't change, and everything inside  tags is changing with each post.

Now, this is multiline text, and I SERIOUSLY have problem finding a matching string, and even tool, that could help me solving this puzzle. I have this spreaded on several blogs, and I figured that instead of spamming my blog with same repetitive code that makes 1/3rd of all content I have in my posts, I can simply include it through single.php

So, I want this permanently deleted from my database.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on blogs or regex, but couldn't you use a python script to substitute all that text to replace it?

Something like this

```
    re.sub(r'     <!--more-->
<br />
<center>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr> 

 [\.]+

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center> 
', "")
```

If I'm not wrong, that should find all the cases where it finds an ad and replace it with a blank string :)

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start with python, or can it even do that with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (always take a backup before testing)

```
global $wpdb;
$posts=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts} LIMIT 0,1");
foreach($posts as $p){
   $pos = strpos($p->post_content, '<!--more-->');
   $more_content = substr($p->post_content,$pos);
   if($pos !== false && strstr($more_content,"myaffiliate.com" && $p->ID>0)){
      $content = substr($p->post_content,0,$pos-1);
      $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_content='%s' WHERE ID=%d",$content,$p->ID));
   }
}
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.

This will remove the post content part after `<!--more-->` if it contains the string `"myaffiliate.com"` (this is somewhat lazy matching, but we could refine it with `preg_match` or `preg_replace` if you need it).

You could use `LIMIT 0,1` while testing and then increase it to your needs.